# MVC4 Project and ImageResizer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

Problem: MVC 4 test application with ImageResizer on any page access responds with "Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule'"

To test and understand how ImageResizer works a MVC4 project was created in VS 2012, a single controller was created to display a HelloWorld page.  Works as expected.

Next step was to add ImageResizer from NuGet. The ImageResizer Web.Config Installation for MVC was installed.  This package added three additional packages:

ImageResizer Web.Config Installation
ImageResizer.MVC - MVC friendly utilitite
ImageResizer

Attempting to run the application results in a yellow screen of death with the "Could not load type 'ImageResizer.InterceptModule.'

Attempt to resolve with no success include:

1. Verify DLLs exist.
2. Remove and reinstall packages.
3. Copy ImageResizer dll from a working webforms application
4. Item 1 on the ImageResizer troubleshooting guide doesn't appear to be the issue "1.Your website has a 'sub-site' (Application Folder) inside it. Application Folders inherit all Web.config settings from their parent sites, yet expect to have their own copies of all the dlls referenced by those settings in their own /bin folder. You can resolve this problem by (a) changing the app folder to a virtual folder, (b) adding a copy of ImageResizer.dll and plugins into the /bin folder inside that application also, or (c) using  statements in the child Web.config to cancel out the inherited  statements from the parent Web.config. Option (c) will disable image resizing within the sub-application."

Yes there is a web.config file in the views directory.  Tried creating and copying image resizer dlls to a bin directory in view - no success.  Tried adding a remove to the web.config in the views directory. Again no success.

Comment: What web server are you running this under? Have you in fact verified there are no sub-applications?

Comment: IIS 7.5 - there are no sub applications

Answer (score 12):

Problem resolved - self inflicted.

It seemed like a good idea to name the test project imageresizer.  Which of course created a dll name imageresizer which walked all over the real imageresizer dll.

Comment: I'm gonna have to add this to the Troubleshooting page. It's the first time I've seen this cause.

Comment: It's worth noting that you can accept this as the correct answer. At the very least, it helps mark this as a "closed" question.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist You never added it :-( http://imageresizing.net/docs/troubleshoot - I did exactly the same thing. As did several others it seems :) Visual Studio really ought to warn against this, but its probably very common for people to create a standalone resizing web project

Comment: oh dear... did the same :o